# How to use bash variables inside make

Tags: bash, make, gnu-make

I thought that `make` interprets the rule's set of commands literally, passing them to the sub-shell. But this doesn't seem to work in this case:

```
default: loop
        echo $$RANDOM
```

This prints `echo $RANDOM` in my shell but doesn't actually print the number.

Answer (score 4):

[GNU make: Choosing the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) says that the default shell is `/bin/sh`.

`$RANDOM` is a bash feature, so you could explicitly tell `make` to use `bash` by putting

```
SHELL := '/bin/bash'
```

at the top of your `Makefile`.

(`echo $RANDOM` is just `make` echoing the command it's going to run.)